Target class [permission] does not exist
I am using laravel 11 and trying to use spatie laravel permission.
But I got error:
  Target class [permission] does not exist.

I read some article, it must be added in kernel.php this code:
'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,

But there is no kernel.php in laravel 11?

According to docs in Laravel 11 the kernel has been refactored, and the configuration of middleware aliases has moved. You may assign aliases to middlewares in your application's bootstrap/app.php file.
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->alias([
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
    ]);
})

